# Why can I not use a discard parameter within a lambda with a discard parameter?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm writing a C# library using the new .NET tooling. I'm trying to use [discards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards) from C# 7.0. I'm running into an issue where the compiler is treating `_` as a parameter and not a discard.

Example:

```
using System;

public delegate void Delegate1(string a, Delegate2 b);
public delegate void Delegate2(int a, Delegate3 b);
public delegate void Delegate3(string a, Delegate4 b);
public delegate void Delegate4(int a, int b);

class Program
{
    void Test(Delegate1 f)
    {
        f("x", (_, g) => {
            g("y", (i, _) => {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Building:

```
% dotnet build                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ~/Source/temp
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.5.179.9764 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Restore completed in 18.6 ms for /Users/me/Source/temp/temp.csproj.
Program.cs(13,24): error CS0136: A local or parameter named '_' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter [/Users/me/Source/temp/temp.csproj]

Build FAILED.

Program.cs(13,24): error CS0136: A local or parameter named '_' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter [/Users/me/Source/temp/temp.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.45
```

Comment: Your error is seen in the docs: Compiler error CS0136

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to use discards, but your scenario has none. The `_` parameters are just regular variables. You can see this if you change the code to add an assignment from the `_` parameter:

```
void Test(Delegate1 f)
{
    f("x", (_, g) => {
        int a = _;

        g("y", (i, _) => {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        });
    });
}
```

Had the `_` in the outer lambda actually been a discard, there would have been a compiler error. But there's not. It's just a plain old variable, and you get a plain old *"that name is used"* error.

Comment: Note that discards for lambda functions is being tracked as a language feature in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/111